# Airflow : Stop Current DAG Execution on event of SLA Miss

Tags: airflow, scheduler

Facing a scenrio in Apache - Airflow , where the ask is to stop the DAG execution on the event of an sla miss and proceed with subsequent DAG interval's execution

Is such a functionality configurable in Airflow ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lightweight DAG that runs every X (the smallest interval within your Airflow cluster) which checks for SLA misses and pauses the DAG if there's any.